# get_permalink() always returns empty

Tags: permalinks

I suddenly have a bug in my plugin, and I don't know what on earth could be causing it.  This code is failing because `get_permalink()` is returning empty at all times:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `".DB_NAME."`.`wp_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'";
$result = mysql_query($select);
while($meta_posts = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ){
    $menu .= "<option value=\"".get_permalink($meta_posts['ID'])."\">".$meta_posts['post_title']."</option>\n";
}
```

It used to work just fine, all it does is return a dropdown menu of all the published WP posts/pages.  Now I get the dropdown full of titles, but there is no permalink in the option value.

Anyone have any ideas why `get_permalink()` would be empty?  I've even tried hardcoding a known postid into it, and it's still empty.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should use `get_posts` instead of a raw SQL query.  Or at least use `$wpdb`.

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        'numberposts' => -1
    )
);
```

Then, try passing the entire post object to `get_permalink`, which [saves some database queries](http://yoast.com/wp-code-snippet/get_permalink-memory-usage-issues/).

```
<?php
foreach( $posts as $p )
{
    $link = get_permalink( $p );
    // do stuff here...
}
```

The only thing I saw in `get_permalink` that might cause an empty string it it checking for an empty post ID.  Try the above, and see if it works for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, this just returns an empty array:  `$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1
    )
);

die(print_r($posts));`

Comment: Just try doing `$posts = get_posts();` without any additional arguments.

Comment: no difference, empty array...

Comment: You do have posts, correct?  Or do you only have pages? Other than that I have no idea why get_permalink or get_posts is not working.  Sorry.

Comment: have both posts and pages.  =(  Can't make any sense of this...

Comment: Disable all plugins. Try again!

Comment: This happens on numerous different WP installs, on different servers, with completely different plugin situations, some with loads of plugins, some with very few.  Plugins don't appear to have anything to do with the issue, unfortunately.  To make things even stranger however, I have ONE install, using the exact same files as another domain on the same server, where it works fine.  But I can't find any common thread yet.

Comment: Just to be sure, deactivated ALL other plugins on one of the "bad" installs, and the problem persists.

Comment: Then maybe it's something elsewhere in your plugin?

Comment: Turns out that for some unknown reason, get_post just is not available to this page of my plugin, unless a specific theme is activated.  No idea why, but on my installs that use this theme (ProfitsTheme) it works fine, but if the theme is not active, it fails.  Moving the "menu construction code" into my initial db_login call (where wp-config.php is called), causes the permalink to work regardless of theme.  Very weird.

Comment: Is this page of your plugin called directly? Plugin pages should never need to be called directly, and when they are, will not have access to WordPress functions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
query_posts( 'post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1' );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $menu .= "<option value=\"".get_permalink(get_the_ID())."\">".get_the_title()."</option>\n";
endwhile;
```